# Jquery - Url checker (rss, audio or video podcast)

Tags: jquery, url, rss, google-api, podcast

i try to built an url checker using the google feed api.

**My problems:**
**1:** the `if(result)` check doesn't work. Maybe an async problem?
**2:** any ideas for the rss,audio/video podcast check? I'm sure, i get in the response an url to the audio/video file (but i'm blind at the moment). 
 My idea is to check this url.

```
// somthing like that
if(typeof xxxx == 'undefined') -> rss feed
if xxxx.match(/mp3|wav|XXX/gi) -> audio feed
if xxxx.match(/mpg|avi|flv/gi) -> video feed
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // valid rss feed
    var result = urlCheck('http://www.bild.de/rssfeeds/vw-home/vw-home-16725562,short=1,sort=1,view=rss2.bild.xml');
    if(result){ console.warn('result1 is a '+result.urlIsA+' '); console.dir(result); }

    // valid video podcast
    var result = urlCheck('http://www.tagesschau.de/export/video-podcast/webl/tagesschau/');
    if(result){ console.warn('result1 is a '+result.urlIsA+' '); console.dir(result); }

    // valid audio podcast
    var result = urlCheck('http://chaosradio.ccc.de/chaosradio-latest.rss');
    if(result){ console.warn('result1 is a '+result.urlIsA+' '); console.dir(result); }

});
function urlCheck(url)
{
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(url);
    feed.setResultFormat(google.feeds.Feed.MIXED_FORMAT);
    feed.setNumEntries('1');
    feed.load(function(result)
    {
        if (!result.error)
        {
            var allEntries = result.feed.entries;
            console.info(url);
            console.dir(allEntries);

            /* if(XXX.match(/XXXX/,gi)) {
                allEntries.urlIsA = 'rss feed';
                return allEntries;
            }
            if(XXX.match(/XXXX/,gi)) {
                allEntries.urlIsA = 'audio podcast';
                return allEntries;
            }
            if(XXX.match(/XXXX/,gi)) {
                allEntries.urlIsA = 'video podcast';
                return allEntries;
            } */

            return false;
        }
        else { return false; }
    });
}
```

**Working example**
http://jsbin.com/unikak/edit#javascript,html 
**notice:** your must copy the code in an *.html file, otherwise you get an error from jsBin

```
google.feeds.Feed is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your RegExps, so that only `mpg` at the end of a string is matched:
`/(mpg|avi|flv/)$/gi`

Instead of using `return`, use callback functions:

```
function urlCheck(url, callback){

....
//Insread of return false:
callback(false);
//Instead of return true:
callback(true);
```

At your result checker:

```
urlCheck("http://....", function(result){
    if(result){
         console.warn(...);
    } else {
       //..
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, works great :). Btw, do you know where the link from the media file is? it must be in the xmlNode, right?

Comment: See the documentation for the tree structure: http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/feed/v1/devguide.html#resultXml